# Javascript create array into another array?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempted to create a simple array, inside of another array.

Excuse me, as I'm a bit new to this, but I am attempting to insert the following:

```
"m1":["username"]
```

into a empty array named:

```
var mg = {}
```

So that it looks like this,

```
var mg = {"m1":["username"]}
```

I attempted to insert it like so,

```
function insertPlayer(mid, user){
mg.push(mid = [user]);
}

insertPlayer("m1", "username")
```

I was using the push function, but it seems to completely ignore me.

This is what I want:

[image]

With the function I was using, I'm getting this:

[image]

If I could get it the way I want, I can easily grab the list of usernames inside 'm1' by easily calling `mg["m1"]`

I'm sure there is an easy fix for this, but I just can't find it. I've been researching for about 30 minutes and decided to ask here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mg` is an object, not an array, it does not have `.push` method.

Instead of `mg.push(mid = [user]);`, it should be `mg[mid] = [user];`.

After that, `mg.mid` is an array, if you want to add new user to it, you could use `.push`,

```
mg[mid].push(user);
```

So the function will like below:

```
// pass mg as a parameter is better than use it as a global in function
function insertPlayer(mg, mid, user){
  if (mg[mid]) {
     mg[mid].push(user);
  } else {
     mg[mid] = [user];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped fix it but - rather than it saying "m1", it says 'mid'. Is there a way to fix this? http://www.imgbomb.com/i/d15/nu7b7.png

Comment: @Alex Check the code I added, use `mg[mid]` instead of `mg.mid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mg = {'m1': []};
```

Then try `mg[mid].push(user);` instead of `mg.push(mid = [user]);`